# Reducing the memory footprint of lists of machine numbers

Tags: performance-tuning, memory

I have a large 1D dataset of double precision numbers that are stored in many external database files. In order to load the whole dataset into Mathematica 8 I iterate over the files `AppendingTo` a `List`. The problem is that my computer keeps running out of memory even though the memory available should be more than enough to store the whole set. When researching the issue I discovered a strange behaviour (see the code below). The list produced by `AppendTo` consumes much more memory than would correspond to the size of an integer. I presume that, in the latter `List`, Mathematica uses some different kind of objects to store the data.

Any suggestions on how to reduce the memory usage?

```
In[78]:= ByteCount[Range[1, 10000]]
Out[78]= 40168

In[79]:= data = List[];
For[i = 0, i &lt 10000, ++i,
  AppendTo[data, i];
];

In[81]:= ByteCount[data]
Out[81]= 320040
```

Comment: In addition to Rojo's answer, for better performance avoid `AppendTo` and do something similar to this: `Join @@ (Import /@ FileNames["data*.txt"])`.  Also avoid `For` if you can.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're looking to [pack your array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496/109).

It's done with `` Developer`ToPackedArray ``

```
dataPacked = Developer`ToPackedArray[data];
ByteCount[dataPacked]

40168
```

There's [more on this](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/TechNotes/391/) following the link.

The links were taken from the packed array section of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/259/5).

Comment: You beat me, have an upvote.